# Get immediate first child element

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm writing a Chrome content script extension and I need to be able to target a specific element that, unfortunately, has no unique identifiers except its parent element.

I need to target the immediate first child element of `parentElement`. `console.log(parentElement)` reports both of the child elements/nodes perfectly, but the succeeding console logs (the ones that target the childNodes) always return an `undefined` value no matter what I do.

**This is my code so far**
<sup>(I have excluded the actual names to avoid confusion and extra, unnecessary explanation)</sup>

```
function injectCode() {

    var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("uniqueClassName");

    if (parentElement && parentElement.innerHTML != "") {

        console.log(parentElement);
        console.log(parentElement.firstElementChild);
        console.log(parentElement.firstChild);
        console.log(parentElement.childNodes);
        console.log(parentElement.childNodes[0]);
        console.log(parentElement.childNodes[1]);

    } else {

        setTimeout(injectCode, 250);
    }   
}
```

How do I select the first child element/node of `parentElement`?

[image]

**Update:**
`parentElement.children[0]` also has the same error as `parentElement.childNodes[0]`.

Comment: Do you want the first child node or the first child **element** (node)?

Comment: don't let any spaces between parent div and child but it in one line

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Both these will give you the first child node:

```javascript
console.log(parentElement.firstChild); // or
console.log(parentElement.childNodes[0]);
```

If you need the first child that is an element node then use:

```javascript
console.log(parentElement.children[0]);
```

**Edit**

Ah, I see your problem now; `parentElement` is an array.

If you know that [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) will only return one result, which it seems you do, you should use `[0]` to dearray (yes, I made that word up) the element:

```javascript
var parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName("uniqueClassName")[0];
```

Comment: Everything returns undefined (as you can see in the image), and when you use a `[0]` it trips up the whole script. 

I just tried `.children[0]` too, and that didn't work either. :/

Comment: @BenHooper Updated my answer since you added the screenshot, I noticed the actual problem.

Comment: Also note , that to get FIRST CHILD **ELEMENT NODE** there is a read-only property `firstElementChild` ..... `ParentNode.firstElementChild`

Comment: childNodes[0] returns nothing, everytime.  It's childNodes[1] aka base1

Comment: No, `childNodes[1]` is always the second child node. Note that if the DOM was constructed with HTML containing whitespace (newline, tab, space, etc) before the HTML tag of the child, then `childNodes[0]` is a TextNode containing that whitespace and `childNodes[1]` is the element node (but it is still the second child).

Comment: Nice use of dearray, I wonder whether you could say unarray (I guess the function is `split()[0]`)

Comment: Careful: `parentElement.firstChild` != `parentElement.childNodes[0]`
for instance parentElement.firstChild will give the first text element (innerText) whereas parentElement.childNodes[0] gives the first dom element (div) in the example <el>innerText<div></div></el>