# div doesn't recognize its child elements (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

Layout of the code:
An .html file & I link to an external .js and .css in head. Various table cells onclick make a "popup" div change its position and become visible. To do this, I made the JS functions reference a global variable which I set by adding
`<script>var popup = document.getElementById('popdiv');</script>`
just above the end of /body.

popdiv has 3 child elements:

```
<div id='popdiv'>
<div class='header'>Time Slot</div>
<div class='xout' onclick='hide(event)'>X</div>
<div class='showtag'>tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5, tag6, tag7, tag8, tag9, tag10, tag11</div>
</div>
```

Anything I do with popup works fine, except when I try to call popup.firstChild, which screws everything up. popup.firstChild.type returns undefined, and popup.childNodes.length returns 7. I gave the nested div an id so I could grab it; [getheader].parentNode.type is also undefined.

And I replaced the .header selector in my .css file with a first-child of popdiv selector (`#popdiv >:first-child`) and its style was still correctly applied; all 3 children will also inherit style attributes like color:red--if I set them in the CSS file. Not so if I set them with JavaScript.

In this case there are other ways I can access the divs, but I want to know for the sake of understanding JavaScript what the heck happened--or if I misunderstand something fundamental about parent-child HTML elements. Did I do something awful that could break other things? (Having the extra script at the end of the file feels wrong, but I don't know the actual reason it doesn't work out fine.)

Thank you in advance

Comment: what are you trying to do with `popup.firstChild`?

Comment: Letoile's solution worked but since you asked: Originally, I was trying to update its innerHTML based on where the user clicked... then there was that debugging point where I was just trying to effect any change on it anyhow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `document.getElementById('popdiv').children[0]` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10474679/769103) - for getting first child. Also you can use `popup.firstElementChild` that give you the same result.

And you can use `document.getElementById('popdiv').children`to get all children.