# Hov do I change style with javascript and affect only first ul?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function showMenu(){
var parentElement =     document.getElementById("menuItem1");
var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
lis[i].setAttribute("style","display: block");
}   
}
```

I want to show only first ul item, when button is clicked.
I am trying to change my webpage from using :hover to display the ul's, 
and use javascript to show the menu onclick..
I am no js expert, but am learning a little, I am still not quite understanding this code.
I tried giving my main li's, of my top ul, Id's.
Like menuItem1 and menuItem2, and this made it possible to show the ul's, for only THAT li, wich is what I want, not open both.

The problem, is that is shows every under-menu as well, and I guess I am missing to tell it to only affect first ul, not every child.
I can think the logic behind it all, but am to unfamiliar with javascript commands. first.child, or something like that I guess is needed someplace, can anyone guide me in the right direction?

I understand that I get the element with Id, this function, and the Tagname, is easy to understand. The rest, well I have much yet to learn, thou I understand it loops throuh the objects, just dont know why, or what it does with that..

So, is there someway, or, what is the way, to affect only the first ul, not every sub-categori?

css and html is functioning ok, but maybe there is also a possibility of doing this WITHOUT changing the 3 main Li's to have unique Id's?

my menu looks something like this:

```
<nav id="cssmenu">
<ul>
<li id="menuItem1"><a href="">menuItem1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">submenu1, no unique ID</a></li>
    <li><a href="">submenu1, no unique ID</a></li>
    </ul>
<li id="menuItem2"><a href="">menuItem2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href=''>submenu2, no uniwue ID</a></li>
    <li><a href=''>submenu2, no unique ID</a>
  *      <ul>
        <li><a href=''>submenu2-2nd column, no unique ID</li>
  *      </ul>
    <li><a href=''>submenu2, no unique ID</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I set a *, where my ul that is not supposed to be opened is. Any way to solve this, without giving unique Id's to every ul? 
I gave the top-li's, menuItem1 etc, unique ID's, and this is about the most I would want to give unique Id's for my menu, as it is   little bit big, on many pages..

And I would rather have Javascript, not jquery, as I haven't learned the use of jquery..

EDIT: edited in Id's of my li's where i have this.. Is it easier to do this with addeventlistener perhaps? Have not used it before, but there I can set action for 1st click, and then close menu for 2nd click, right? Thanks in advance for any help!:)

RE-EDIT:
Code you supplied worked fine, just not hiding the ul's again.

```
function Meny(){ 
var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu"); 
var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul"); 
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) { 
lis[i].setAttribute("style","background: red"); } }
```

But this does, and if I change it do display:none, it hides the whole thing, wich I really dont want, then my menu dissapears..
How is this working? I must have surely missed something essential here, and as you understand I am learning javascript, not saying I know it very well ;)

Comment: I am in simplicity, trying to transform my :hover, to onclick function, wich is causing some headace :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can delete the loop in your javascript and use an argument pointing the clicked DOM element (here the **li**) :

```
function showMenu(parentElement){
    var uls= parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
    if (uls.length > 0)
        uls[0].setAttribute("style","display: block");
}
```

Then you can use **onclick** attributes of the li tag and calling the showMenu function with this as argument :

```
<nav id="cssmenu">
<ul>
<li id="menuItem1" onclick="showMenu(this)"><a href="#">menuItem1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">submenu1, no unique ID</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">submenu1, no unique ID</a></li>
    </ul>
<li id="menuItem2" onclick="showMenu(this)"><a href="#">menuItem2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>submenu2, no uniwue ID</a></li>
    <li onclick="showMenu(this)"><a href='#'>submenu2, no unique ID</a>
  *      <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>submenu2-2nd column, no unique ID</li>
  *      </ul>
    <li><a href='#'>submenu2, no unique ID</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The other method is to use a function called after loading the page to apply **addeventlistener** to each **li** tag instead of using the **onclick** attribute.

```
<body onload="load();">
```

With the corresponding function :

```
function load(){ 
    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            showMenu(this);
        }); 
    }
}
```

Be careful, all browsers don't manage the **addEventListener** function, for Internet Explorer you may have to use **attachEvent** instead.
Libraries like jQuery manages these difference in a transparent way for the developer, so it could be simpler in many cases to use it instead of pure JavaScript.

Comment: Cannot seem to get this to work, i guess since I have an onclick attached to every menu item?

have heard that the addeventListener is not supported in like IE, but really, my menu have other problems in ie8, where it does not hide anything, and displays it all as blocks..

So I guess a better solution would be to rethink my menu, as it is alot of ul -li - ul etc..

Comment: worked as a charm, the this keyword is something I had not considered :)

Thou I met one issue, it wont close, the previous opened menu.
Say I open the first submenu, and want to go back to the mainsubmenu(first ul), and open another submenu.

I will try and figure it out, seems I am only missing one big IF command :)
If clicked elsewhere, close, If clicked on another li, then close..
Is this also something for addEventListener?

Comment: Adding a clickevent to the body, will be one solution i guess, to then set it to display none again...
 Can I use the code I had in the first place, to reverse this when parent is clicked a second time, or sibling is clicked?
Thinking to add something like this

    if(user.click.elsewhere){
    lis[i].setAttribute("style","display: none");
    }

Comment: function Meny(){
    var parentElement = document.getElementById("cssmenu");
        var lis = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
     lis[i].setAttribute("style","background: red");
         }
    }

Why is this code hiding the menu the way I need it to?
If I change to display,none, instead of color-red, it hides everything in the menu.
Having color-red, it only hides the ul's, what am i missing? :o
Everything else works good, thanks for the guidance mr @Pikalchemist

Answer (score 0):

[Get immediate first child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474676/get-immediate-first-child-element)

Found the answer, just change my [i] to [0].. 
Really a pain in the # to ask the correct question sometimes :D

This obviously stops my array-loop, or something, and targets only what I want.. 
Trying now to get it to work with every submenu, removing the need for unique ID's is the way to go I guess..